# Variable and string concentation confusion

Tags: python, variables, concatenation

I am watching a youtube tutorial by freecodecamp.org on python and the instructor is building a translator that translates all vowels into a g. I don't understand how having + "g" replaces a character as opposed to just being added onto the end of the variable string, also, how does the input get applied to the translation variable? All help is greatly appreciated.

video in question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw   2:58:00

```
def function(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in "AEIOUaeiou":
            translation = translation + "g"    **<-----how does this replace the letter with g and not just add g to the end of the string?**
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
    return translation

print(function(input("Enter a phrase: ")))
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me, because the `g` *is* "just being added onto the end of the variable string". I'd recommend using e.g. http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html to step through it.

Comment: Take a pen and a piece of paper (or an interactive debugger) and step through it line by line and note the value of each variable at each step…

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184412/discussion-on-question-by-deejlp-variable-and-string-concentation-confusion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the function is adding "g" to the new string `translation`, not `phrase`.

`translation = ""` means that `translation` is just a blank, empty string.

```
if letter in "AEIOUaeiou":
    translation = translation + "g"
```

means that: "if the letter is a vowel, add "g" to `translation`".

```
else:
    translation = translation + letter
```

means that: "if the letter is not a vowel, add the letter to the string `translation`".

`return translation` means output `translation`, and forget all about `phrase`.

Finally, `print` prints the result out.

Comment: thank you that is clear, can you explain how the input statement at the bottom of the code gets tied to the function exactly? is there a way to call the function with an arugement that does not require input?

Comment: The `input` statement isn't actually "tied" to the function; it's just there so that when you execute the code as a file, the code will ask the user (the human behind the keyboard) to provide some input to run the function on and then print the output.

Comment: perfect, just reworked it to work without an input and its pretty clear now thank you for the help

Comment: Another way to use the function but without `input()` is to copy all of that code onto your python interpreter in the terminal and replace `print(function(input("Enter a phrase: ")))` with `print(function("Whatever phrase or string you want here"))`

Comment: yupp, just did exactly that and its making more sense, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is being replaced, because `translation` is being created character-by-character, rather than starting as a copy of `phrase`.

Given `function("foobar")`, the value of `translation` at each step would be

```
translation = ""         # initially
translation = "f"        # add f
translation = "fg"       # add g, not o
translation = "fgg"      # add g, not o
translation = "fggb"     # add b
translation = "fggbg"    # add g, not a
translation = "fggbgr"   # add r
```

(FYI, such translations are easier using the `string` module:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.translate("foobar", string.maketrans("AEIOUaeiou", "gggggggggg"))
'fggbgr'
```

)

Comment: thank you that clears it up a bit, it just threw me off because:

    translation = ("This is a string")
translation = translation + "g"
print(translation)

output: This is a stringg

This clearly just adds the g to the end of the string while looking very similar to the code in my example, but your explanation clears it up a bit

Comment: Where do you see `translation = ("This is a string")`?

Comment: sorry, that was some example code I drew up to illustrate how:

translation = translation + "g" will add to a string in my later example, it's hard to format properly in comments my apologies, I was able to run it through a visualizer and it's making more sense to me similar to your example, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It "replaces" because of the `if ...` `else: ...` condition you have. When the contition is matched (the letter is a vowel), it appends a g (not the actual letter), `else` it appends the actual letter. But actually you are creating a new string from scracth, appending the letters as they are if they are not vowels or `g` otherwise.